# Cannot connect to mysql database from VM using java

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

On my host computer I have installed Wamp and I can connect using PHP for example, or the browser. My client is a virtual machine with Linux and I am trying to connect to the database on the host to add some entries there.

Here is my code:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236:8080/fps";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
    System.out.println("Database connection established");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Database connection terminated");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I must mention that I'm trying to connect over a local network, and also that I setup Wamp to work on port 8080 (it can be seen above). Another thing is that, on the virtual machine, I can access the database using a browser.

The code above generates an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:628)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1014)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>       at DatabaseConnection.main(DatabaseConnection.java:12)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2926)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:560)
>       ... 16 more

I believe the problem could be from the settings of mysql on the client, in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf but I don't really know how to change them since I didn't find an example for this particular situation. I also thought that the fact that I changed the port to 8080, when mysql normally uses 3306, could be causing problems.

So, the question is, how could I make this work? Thanks.

Edit: I also want to add that the port change (to 8080) was made in the conf file of apache on the server. This by default is 80. So maybe it shouldn't affect the 3306 of mysql.

Comment: Problem may be in the network communication. Make sure you are able to ping the host and make sure `mysql` running on 8080 port.

Comment: What about mysql-connector.jar file ? did you add it ?

Comment: i think mysql port is from 3306 to 3309

Comment: Does it work if you change port back to 3306?

Comment: Verify and test DB server with ping.

Comment: Why did you change the MYSQL Listening port?? Its odd that something else was using 3306 unless you have 2 MySQL servers running on your host.

Comment: Ping works from client to server IP. Also, I added the connector.

Comment: what about port 8080 availability? Make sure mysql is running on 8080 or change to 3306 and try

Comment: Please see the edit to the question

Comment: From your edit it looks like you changed port on which you are connecting to HTTP server, not to database. Try to connect on default MySQL port 3306.

Comment: @Pshemo well I did not change any settings to mysql on the VM so it should be using the default port, that being 3306

Comment: Than why `8080` is used in your `String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236:8080/fps";`? You are not trying to connect to HTTP server, but MySQL database management system.

Comment: So what do you suggest? Should I try to connect to 
"jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236/fps" or
"jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236:3306/fps" ?

Comment: Try both, they shoudl both work

Comment: `3306` is default port so if you will skip it in URL it will be added automatically by JDBC. So `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236/fps` is the same as `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236:3306/fps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another thing is that, on the virtual machine, I can access the
>   database using a browser.

By this do you mean you can run a web site that lives on the HOST from the browser on the VM. Thats not quite that same thing as connecting from a remote PC. In this case the code running i.e. PHP I assume, is running on the HOST and connecting from PHP to MYSQL all of which are ON THE HOST.

By default the `root` account, if thats what you are using is only allowed to connect if it is being run from the same PC as MySQL is running on.

Try creating a new MySQL user account, make sure that this new account is allowed to login to MySQL from the ip of the VM.

For example:

```
CREATE USER 'Florina'@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'A-Password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Your_Database TO 'Florina'@'192.168.1.%';
```

This should allow the account `Florina` to connect to the MYSQL Server from any address on your subnet, so it wont matter if the VM gets different ip addresses after each reboot.

It would also be a good idea to check that you Firewall is allowing remote connections to port 8080! And 3306 if your just confused about the port change.

In fact **are you sure** you changed MYSQL to listen on port 8080 or did you change **Apache** to listen on port 8080. If you changed apache then you would be entering a url in the browser with the `:8080`. **This does not mean that MySQL is listening on port 8080** In this case remove the `:8080` from your

```
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.236/fps";
```

Comment: Its not about permission or access denied. it is about communication error.

Comment: By "using a browser", I meant I can access 
http://192.168.1.236:8080/phpmyadmin/

Comment: See that last paragraph, I dont think you changed MySQL to listen on 8080, it was Apache that you changed! If that fixes/changes the error, then create the new MySQL account and change the login details accordingly

Comment: @Sridhar No its about a small confusion about changing the Apache listening port and thinking that would also effect MySQL DBMS Listening port as well

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I made a new user, stopped my firewall completely and removed the :8080 and it went fine.

Answer (score 0):

normally the  mysql DB is listening to the 3306port and not to 8080 port unless u change it

If the 8080 port number is correct please try to ping the IP adress from the VM command line and check if ur mysql service is UP .

Comment: Ping works just fine. However, I checked if mysql was running with mysqladmin -u root -p status and I get an error:

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Comment: did u execute that command line from the VM ?  if yes try to include the host with mysql  -h 192.168.1.236 -u root -p , and tell me what did u get

Comment: Running mysql -h 192.168.1.236 -u root -p doesn't give any output, it seems stuck. I assume it will give a timeout

Comment: what about mysqladmin -h 192.168.1.236 -u root -p ?

Comment: The output is exactly like if I would've run mysqladmin -?
I tried multiple times, just to be sure there are no typos, same result.

Comment: Unless you have chnaged the `root` user it is only allowed to connect from the PC running MYSQL. For obvious security reasons!!!

Comment: this is Strange cauz normaly mysql sever is started with the default option which is  --bind-address=0.0.0.0 , means that the root has the ability to connect from an external client machine ..  do not understand why mysql command line doesnt respond from  VM command line  and it was abvious that  her code doesnt work  cauz of a wrong port number

Answer (score -1):

try using: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

instead of: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` is first step of what OP already have, removing `newInstance()` shouldn't change nothing. Also drivers implementing JDBC 4 don't even require `Class.forName` call.